# how to properly overload operator cast char* in C++?

Tags: c++, string, operator-overloading, return-value

I have a class with a numeric value. 
I need to add a operator overload that , when cast to char* (or wchar*) returns a string with the readable value.

I tried with

```
VAR::operator char*()
{
  STRING test;
  test.format("%d",value); //fills string with "readable" data
  return test.Get() //returns the char* content of the test;
}
```

but the call of the destructor of STRING deletes the value and it returns random data.

Any idea?

Comment: This is C++. We only speak `std::string`ish around here. `char *` is so C-ish.

Comment: I need it to modify a framework, and I can't use std::string.

Comment: btw, if it where a std::string the problem would persist.

Comment: If you can't change the return type, use a buffer member, copy the formatted string there and return a pointer to the buffer, or, if you are the dirty type, use a global static buffer and do the same.

Comment: Implicit conversion is treacherous, so I would first reconsider the whole idea of the conversion operator. Is it *really* necessary, or is explicit conversion the way forward?

Comment: No, the problem will would not "persist". That's a 100% money-back guarantee. std::string manages itself completely. Returning it will give the caller a fully constructed object, representing a string, and the object will exist as long as the caller needs it for. This is what std::string is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that unless you require that caller should call `delete[]` on the pointer returned.

```
VAR::operator char*()
{
  char* test = new char[required_bytes];
  // Fill 'test'
  return test;
}
```

It's better and more sensible to just return a `std::string` (or `std::wstring`) object. When the caller wants a C-string out of it, they can call `c_str()` method of `w/string`.

Answer (score 1):

> Any idea?

1. Use strings rather than char pointers.

   VAR::operator STRING();
2. If not 1. then return a fresh copy of string.

`char const *retVal = new char[test.size() + 1];
std::strncpy(retVal, test.Get(), test.size());
retVal[test.size()] = '\0';
return retVal;`.

(Don't forget to `delete[]` it later.)

3. Finally, you can make `test` your class's member and return its contents; then it will survive past the function's end.